# Android Gridview error , displaying last item incorrectly

Tags: android, gridview

i have a grid view, this is how i implement it

```
<GridView
    android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/homeGrid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" />
```

which aim to display 7 items using custom adapter, and this is how i implement the adapter

```
private Context mContext;
private final String[] item;
private final int[] imageId;

public GridAdapter(Context c, String[] item, int[] imageId) {
    mContext = c;
    this.item = item;
    this.imageId = imageId;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return item.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return item[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View grid;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_grid_layout, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        textView.setText(item[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    } else {
        grid = convertView;
    }
    return grid;

}
```

}

and then i initiate it in my activity like this

`GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(HomePage.this, title, imageId);
        GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.homeGrid);`

the problem is that the app displaying the last position which is position 6 as position 0, strangly i implement onitemclicklistener to my gridview and i got the correct position when i click the last position.

where is my mistake ?

Comment: Your Adapter is OK, put your onItemClick code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_grid_layout, null);
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

    textView.setText(item[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

    return convertView;

}
```